# Simple JSON issue with kendo-grid

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Was wondering if you could help me, I've been battling with trying to get my rest JSON data to display correctly in a kendo-grid for a few hours now, and have just worked out it's due to additional nodes on my JSON

```
$(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: {
                "ttPortalCommunicationResult": [{
                    "UniqueID": 7,
                    "DocumentTitle": "Expense Contribution Scheme Guide",
                    "ActivationDate": "2012-05-22",
                    "DeactivationDate": "2020-05-12",
                    "CategoryDesc": "Operational news"
                }],
            },

            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
                data: "ttPortalCommunicationResult"
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

I get an error `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`.

My question is how can I use only the "ttPortalCommunicationResult" node on JSON data which contains the additional nodes?

I would have assumed kendo would understand how to traverse to that node. An explanation why it can't would also be nice.

Comment: the two links are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataSource schema parse method

```
schema: {
    parse : function(data) {
        return data.ttPortalCommunicationResult;
    }
}
```